# Returning an unique record for multiple users

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get time between 2 dates. I've got a table with different holidays, DateTime and userId. There is several different holidays but what counts for me are Christmas and Easter.
I would like to get time from the oldest logged holiday to the newest for every single user. (doesn't matter Christmas or Easter it was)

Now I get only get result for one user. 
I tried also WHERE holiday LIKE 'Christmas' OR/AND 'EASTER' but doesn't work properly.

```sql
WITH XYZ as(
SELECT userID,
max(dt) as the_oldest,
min(dt) as the_newest, 
datediff(max(dt), min(dt))
FROM data
WHERE holiday NOT LIKE 'Halloween') 
SELECT * FROM XYZ;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post sample data set with expected output.

Comment: If you want this particular record for EACH user, u need a group by userID.

Comment: @iguypouf that's it, many thanks for helping me:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `GROUP BY` userID so that query will return max and min date for each user.

```
SELECT userID,
max(dt) as the_newest,
min(dt) as the_oldest,
datediff(max(dt), min(dt))
FROM data
WHERE holiday NOT LIKE 'Halloween'
GROUP BY userID
```

Please note `max(dt)` will give newest date and `min(dt)` oldest. It was opposite in your query.